# Minimum dimension of a nullspace of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that the dimension of the nullspace of a linear mapping is at least some integer?  For example, let $$L: P_5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$

How do I prove that $dim(ker(L) \geq 4$, and that equality holds if and only if $L$ is onto?

I can use the rank-nullity theorem to arrive at $2+dim(ker(L)) = 6$ but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea. We want to use the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps (or the rank-nullity theorem as you called it) to provide a lower bound on the dimension of the kernel of $L$. Well, what do we know:

$$ dimnull(L) +dimrange(L) = dim(\mathcal{P}_5)$$

We know that $dimrange(L)≤2$, because it attains the maximum value of $2$ if it is surjective, else it is $0$ or $1$. Also, $dim(\mathcal{P}_5)=6$. We have:

$$dimnull(L) ≥ dim(\mathcal{P}_5)-max(dimrange(L)) \implies dimnull(L)≥6-2=4 \therefore dimnull(L)≥4$$

Note that when I write $max(dimrange(L))$, I mean the highest value it can attain.